# iPad air3 gets stuck in a boot loop and cannot be restored

Tags: ipad

My friend's iPad air 3 seems to be stuck in a boot loop where the Apple logo flashes up for a second and then disappears, then re-appears etc etc. I can put it into recovery mode by holding down the power + home buttons and initially tried to do an update but the update kept failing, then I tried to do a factory reset which also fails. When I looked in the system log on my Mac I saw the following:

[image]

Every time I try it, within a couple of seconds of starting the recovery it fails and enters a "disconnected state". The iPad is definitely still physically connected to the Mac, I don't believe there's a problem with the cable as it works fine for charging and it only enters this "disconnected state" when the recovery process begins.

I'm out of ideas of how to fix this, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: Charging and data are different conductors in the cable. I've had Lightning cables which looked physically OK, charged just fine, but data was just awful to non-existent. Get a known good cable.

Comment: I've just tried it with a second cable and I get the same thing, I'm also the second person to attempt to fix this and the first guy used yet another cable and had the same problem.